# customize section header uilabel background and text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am currently creating my own custom section headers but I have never dont any text editing via code.. and my new method that I am using to populate my custom header is doing some weird things as shown[image] below

I would like to change the text to white and be slightly bolder and also make the white background transparent..

this is the code I am using to do this

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    // Add the label
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.5, 20, 20)];

    // do whatever headerLabel configuration you want here


    headerLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    // Return the headerView
    return headerView;
}
```

I have tried this

```
[headerLabel.backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

etc but its not working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to change the text to white...

UILabel's textColor property is your friend here.

> And slightly bolder...

No problem!  `headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:mySize];`

> And make a white transparent background.

Whoa, whoa, that is the worst setter syntax ive ever seen!!!  My lord, myLabel.backgroundColor is a ***getter***, change:

```
[headerLabel.backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

to:

```
[headerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Lucky for you, using your syntax would have just sent a message to nil, which is defaulting the background color of your label to white.

Comment: `headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` should work too ;)

Comment: @Costique, mon dieu! anything but setting a getter.

Comment: @CodaFi +1 because you are funny and point blank at giving answers

Comment: lol.. thank you very much CodaFi.. I shall learn from my mistakes you so elegantly pointed out ahahah :P

Answer (score 2):

Use following code...

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

UILabel *headername = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 270, 34)];
headername.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headername.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
if(section == 0)
{
    headername.text = @"Name that u wish";
}

else
{
    headername.text = @"Name that u wish";
}
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIImageView *tempimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300,34)];
tempimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whitebackground.png"];

[headerView addSubview:tempimage];
[headerView addSubview:headername];

return  headerView;
}
```

Hope, this will help you...chill

Answer (score 0):

all i have done to get the customized header in table is as following and it is working fine for me

```
UIView *containerView =
    [[[UIView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)]
    autorelease];
UILabel *headerLabel =
    [[[UILabel alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)]
    autorelease];
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Header for the table", @"");
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;
```

i just put it in `viewDidLoad:` method