# Background Images In UITableView Sections Hides Section Titles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am using the following method to set titles in the section's header of UITableView, works fine.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionHeader = nil;

    if (section == 0)
    {
        sectionHeader = nil;
    }
    if(section == 1)
    {
        sectionHeader = @"Categories";
    }
    if (section == 2) {
        sectionHeader = @"General";
    }
    return sectionHeader;
}
```

Using the following method, i am setting the height for header in section, works fine.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}
```

BUT, as soon as i set the background images in the section header using the following method, the titles in section's header disappears and become empty but of course with the image place.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    UIImageView *headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"section_background.png"]];

    headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20);

    [headerView addSubview:headerImage];

    return headerView;
}
```

How can i set the titles in section headers without removing the background images in it. Can somebody be kind enough to point it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168961

this will help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happening because your `headerView` overlap on you **title of Header**. so Best way is...also add `UILabel` To your `headerView`. and give text of label as your title os header in section.

I try with following code .. use it as your way, may be helpful in your case.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    UIImageView *headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]]; //set your image/

    UILabel *headerLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 205, 15)];//set as you need
    headerLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLbl.text = [self.listOfHeader objectAtIndex:section];
    [headerImage addSubview:headerLbl];

    headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20);

    [headerView addSubview:headerImage];

    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach by setting dimensions of CGRect directly from image H, W,

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
 UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];

 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

  headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 300, 25)];
  headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:15.0];
  headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is Header ;)"];
  NSLog(@" headerLabel.text: %@", myString);
  headerLabel.text = myString;
 [imageView addSubview:headerLabel];

 [tempView addSubview:imageView];

 return tempView ;

 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 50;
 }
```